# Resize an image in a PictureBox until it is the size of the original image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I want an image within a PictureBox that will adjust automatically depending on the size of the window but, not larger than the original image. While `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` almost does this, when the PictureBox is larger than the image it causes the image to pixelate. I'm currently executing this code on resize:

```
if (pBox.Height * pBox.Height < pBox.Image.Width * pBox.Image.Height) pBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
else pBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
```

While this works most of the time, occasionally the image won't revert back to zoom:

[image: image still on 'CenterImage']
[image: full image]

Any better way to go about this?

Comment: Which event do you execute the code for image resizing?

Comment: @Ephraim the `ReSize` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting the maximum size to the image size:

```
pictureBox1.MaximumSize = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
```

In Combination with :

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Comment: can I also using this method somehow keep the image centered?

Comment: @AnalogMoose you can center the picture box itself inside an panel.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "if (pBox.Width * pBox.Height < pBox.Image.Width * pBox.Image.Height)" if() Statement. Both dimensions of pBox is taken as height, might cause some problem. Check it